# How can I turn an AngularJS template into a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, render

I want to pass my variables into that template, let it render, and then get the resulting HTML as a string.

How can I do that in AngularJS? Is there a similar function to the `render_to_string()` [function in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)?

The issue is that I have an `email.html` template (you know, layouting emails is painful) and I would like to populate it with variables.

Let´s asume that the content of the `email.html` is sth like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
    <div>We will contact you soon in this email address: {{ email }}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have an object: `data = {name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@bar.com' }`

I would then expect sth similar to:

`let messageBodyHtml = render('path_to_email.html', data)`

And in the end, that `messageBodyHtml` would contain a string with this content:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Foo</h1>
    <div>We will contact you soon in this email address: foo@bar.com</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try compiling your `HTML` programmatically. First, remove `html`, `head` and `body` tags from your template, you don't need them.

**email.html**

```
<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
<div>We will contact you soon in this email address: {{ email }}</div>
```

Use the service `$compile` to compile your template.

```
angular.controller('someController', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){

    var templateString = '<div ng-include="\'./email.html\'" ></div>';
    var newElem = angular.element(templateString);

    $compile(newElem)($scope); // or use $scope.$new()

    // use $timeout to wait until the $digest end and template is fetched/compiled
    $timeout(function(){
        // use .html() to get the final HTML
        console.log(newElem.html());
    });

}]);
```

Fetch your template using `ngInclude`, create an `element` with your template using `angular.element`, `$compile` it, use `$timeout` to wait until the end and then use `newElem.html()`.

Place this code inside a function or a directive.

Hope it helps

Comment: The `$compile` service is the right direction! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure if I understand your question but I believe this will help.

So you wish to express some variables into a template and render them. This sounds almost like string formatting if I understand you. In AngularJS you can use what is called template literals. I partially believe you will require ES2015 or upwards, although I am not fully sure of which JavaScript specification is was introduced as it was called something else.

With literals you can define something like this:

```
let name = 'Bob';

// Notice the use of backqoutes instead of standard quotation syntax
let templateString = `<div class="content"> ${name} </div>`;
```

You used name as an expression which will be rendered as the string is initialized.

This can also be used for multi line strings instead of the painful \n or + to concatenate strings together.

Edit: for more about this you can view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

You'll see you can do quite a lot with this functionality

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my question to make it clearer. I knew about string formating. It would work, but the `html`content that I would like to include is huge, you know how painful an email template layout is :)